# Facebook comments on my website

Tags: php, facebook, comments, disqus

I had a movie related forum in my website. There is a commenting system for each movie and artist. Simply users can add comments.

Now I would likes to implement facebook commenting system to my application . My little worry is how to implement all these two ( fb and my own system )?

Also I had a doubt ..

If I put / share the link on this site on the facebook and assumes that users commented inside facebook .. Then there is any option to print that comments in my web site in that page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook comments is a social plugin that could be embedded in your web page. Specifically it's implemented inside an iframe. Since that iframe is implemented on facebook so you don't need to worry about how to generate the content. Although it looks like appear in your web page.

However if you do need to access the comments data (programmatically), you could retrieve the comments via facebook graph api: https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids={YOUR_URL}. You can also subscribe facebook events to get aware when someone has commented on your movie.

Ref:

1. facebook comments plugin: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/
2. facebook event subscription: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply and ... One more doubt is how to implement my own commenting system ( which I wrote in PHP ) as well as facebook commenting system in a single , dynamic page ?

Comment: I didn't get you honestly. What do you mean implement both in a single page? As I said before, facebook comment system is implemented inside the iframe which is completely out of your control.